# Can this prevent XSS?

Tags: xss, injection

In PHP, I've always used this to represent inputs and textareas:

`$foo = trim(htmlentities($_POST['foo'], ENT_QUOTES);  // the trim is to prevent empty submissions`

Can it also be valid to prevent SQL injection attacks?

Comment: The answer to your SQLi question is no.

Comment: We need context. Where is `$foo` being used? Using `htmlentities` might be undesirable in this context depending on what you're doing with the user-provided data.

Comment: The headline and the tags read "XSS" (Cross-Site-Scripting), the question body "SQL injection". These are two different things. Which one is it you are asking about?

Comment: The SQLI was intended as just an optional question

Comment: @BenJunior when asking questions, please be more clear about what your main question is and make sure your title and body are in alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sql statement:

```
 select * from foo where numerical_id=$foo;
```

The POST request

```
 foo=1;drop%20table%20foobar;
```

The resulting value in `$foo`

```
 foo=1;drop table foobar;
```

The resulting SQL statement

```
 select * from foo where numerical_id=foo=1;drop table foobar;
```

> Can it also be valid to prevent SQLIs?

Obviously no.

---

As for the XSS: Your PHP:

```
<?php
$foo = trim(htmlentities($_POST['foo'], ENT_QUOTES));
print "<script>numerical_id=$foo;</script>"
?>
```

The POST request

```
foo=10;document.write(...)
```

The result

```
<script>numerical_id=10;document.write(...)</script>
```

Since you cannot use quotes in `...` you can construct your strings with `String.fromCharCode` or similar, so no need to give a quoted string.

> Can this prevent XSS?

Obviously also no, at least not general XSS.

---

In general: **Different context has different escaping rules**. `htmlentities` is useful for HTML context, but not for URL context, JS context, CSS context, SQL context ... . And it gets more complex, like dynamically adding code to an `onclick` attribute has both HTML and JS context.